# Cleaning up URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a blogspot website. In Blogspot, you can select different themes to view a page (i.e classic, mosaic, flipcard etc.).

In Google Analytics, in All Pages report, all of them are shown separately.

```
/?view=flipcard
/?view=classic
/?view=mosaic
/?view=magazine
/?view=sidebar
/?view=snapshot
/?view=timeslide
```

I want to see them as my home page in my reports.

The same thing happens with the sub-pages as well. For example, this is an article in my blog, but I see two different entries in my reports.

```
/2014/05/deneme.html?view=snapshot
/2014/05/deneme.html?view=mosaic
```

I want to see all these articles as `/2014/05/deneme.html` in my reports.

Do I need to create different filters for each and every article in my blog?

What is going to happen if I add new articles, do I need to add the filters right after publishing my article to prevent this happening for my future articles?

Can you help me with the advanced filter setup in Analytics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, no need to add different filters, just add *View* to the Exclude Query Parameter option under View > View Settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Blexy for your fast reply:) I should probably try it in a new view to keep my raw data as is. By using "exclude URL query parameters", all those different pageviews (i.e mosaic, classic etc.) will be summed up as one entry in my Content Reports, right? Thanks.

Comment: For future data, yes. Historical data won't be changed (alas).

Comment: @user3790739, correct. It's best practice to have one view as unfiltered, and then have a view that has your various profile filters, and the exclude url params, etc.